# Why setAutoCommit(false) is not working in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to do a transaction in JDBC for an application I'm developing but `Connection#setAutoCommit(false)` seems not to work. Here's the code:

```java
String insertCliente = "INSERT INTO Cliente VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
String vendiAuto = "{CALL VendiAuto(?,?,?,?)}";
try
{
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(insertCliente);
    CallableStatement statement2 = connection.prepareCall(vendiAuto);
    statement1.setString(1,CF);
    statement1.setString(2,nome);
    statement1.setString(3,cognome);
    statement1.setDate(4,new Date(new GregorianCalendar(anno,mese,giorno).getTimeInMillis()));
    statement1.setString(5,luogo);
    statement1.setString(6,sesso);
    statement2.setString(1,codice);
    statement2.setString(2,venditore);
    statement2.setString(3,CF);
    statement2.setBigDecimal(4,prezzoVendita);

    statement1.execute();
    statement2.execute();

    connection.commit();
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
    connection.rollback();
    throw e;
}
finally
{
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

If `statement2.execute()` fails, `statement1.execute()` has effect despite `connection.rollback()` being called.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong.
I don't know how to resolve. Can you help me?
The DBMS used is MySQL 8.0.18 and the tables engine is InnoDB.

Comment: Have you verified that your code actually does enter the `catch` block when the second statement fails? It is a `CallableStatement` and sometimes a stored procedure will throw an error that doesn't immediately trigger a JDBC exception.

Comment: Are your sure your tables InnoDB and not MyISAM by any chance? In any case, please provide a [mre] which includes the relevant DDL.

Comment: @GordThompson It enters the `catch` block; I have verified it with debug

Comment: @MarkRotteveel https://imgur.com/8ZplWCi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` had conflict with my stored procedure: in the procedure, there was already a transaction (defined with `START TRANSACTION`) and somehow it conflicted with the statement.
I solved removing the transaction from the stored procedure.